# CodeIgniter cannot find anything other than default_controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am very new to CodeIgniter so obviously I have problem with the most basic things. I have recently tried to implement a website on local environment. I am using WAMP and the website is in www/public_html. Now the website is working on my localhost but if I try to navigate to any other page from the default (default_controler) it returns not found like

```
The requested URL /public_html/signin/login/ was not found on this server
```

I assumed that the website was designed to resolve its path related problems by itself. I am obviously missing something very basic.

I have changed the base_url in the config.php file by the way.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/public_html/';
```

I have no clue where else the base_url are or where to change it. Any help will greatly appreciated.

Zain

Comment: Do you access the site by `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost/public_html` ?

Comment: using http://localhost/public_html/ . the Default _controller works. If i change it from 'Welcome' to 'signin' controller it works. But wont go any where from there.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this problem because you don't have your .htaccess file configured correctly.  At the document root in your `.htaccess` file you need the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In your `config.php` you will need to do

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

You also need to make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled

Comment: This. Or in the config.php set `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` for your test on local machine if you can't have mod_rewrite enabled (happens).

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this.

Comment: I have put this in my .htaccess file and removed all others. Still no change.

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Try entering this page `http://localhost/public_html/index.php/signin/login/`. Use `site_url('signin/login')` for creating urls to your site and `form_open('signing/login');` as form openings.

Comment: the pages actually work if I access them like  `http://localhost/public_html/index.php/signin/login/` 
I'll look into the site_urls

Comment: Then just instead of using static urls like: `http://localhost/public_html/signin/login` use as I stated before. It should fix your problems.

Answer (score -3):

ther is a problem with your index.php.  check this line

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

if it works u have to add an ht access file to remove index.php from ur url

there are a lot of code for .htaccess file on web try using one that suits you

Comment: If using index.php , it goes in `$config['index_page']`, not `$config['base_url']`.

Comment: yaa it the same thing.. it works even if u use it in base url ..just to check

Comment: It may work in a few circumstances, but still shouldn't be done as it can mess with url functions. For example, `base_url()` is meant to return `$config['base_url']` without the index page.

Comment: yes but no one will use it.. i m just saying u can use it to check...if this is the problem you will anyhow add htaccess file to remove it

Comment: it's actually already like this in the config file `$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/public_html/";
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";`

Comment: the pages actually work if I access them like 

`http://localhost/public_html/index.php/signin/login`

now this is the problem. All the forms are made to redirect to 

`http://localhost/public_html/signin/login`

Comment: u need to add an htaccess file